Why is my state "detail" always empty when only trying to empty it on modal closure?
I am attempting to create some logic for dynamically creating a carousel if a part has more than one image to be show (detail represents that it does). However, while setting the detail works, if I attempt to reset it on modal closure the state is constantly empty. This might be trivial and may be because I do not fully understand useEffect correctly but nonetheless help would be appreciated.
Here is my current block:
const gridData = usePopulateGrid<GridContent>();

  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [focusItem, setFocusItem] = useState<any>(null);
  const [detail, setDetail] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const modalRef = useRef<any>();

  //

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isModalOpen){
      if (focusItem.hasDetail){
        setDetail(focusItem.detailPicture.split(";"));
        console.log("this part does: " + detail);
      }
    }
  },[isModalOpen])

  const handleOpen = (item) => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
    setFocusItem(item);

  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
    setFocusItem(null);
    setDetail([]);

    
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleClickOutside(event) {
      if (
        modalRef.current &&
        !modalRef.current.contains(event.target) &&
        modalRef.current.id == "open"
      ) {
        handleClose();
        
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, []);

I have tried moving the "setDetail([])" call in the handleClickOutside function as well, though from my understanding it achieves the same result as handleClose is called within it anyways.
